# How to use rails before_action conditional for only some actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I have a controller with many actions (let's say `action1`, `action2`, `action3`, and `action4`). I have a `before_action` filter I'd like to exclude on some actions, close to:

```
before_action :filter_thing, except: [:action3, :action4]
```

However, I want the filter to be conditionally called for `action2`.

I tried simply splitting it into two `before_action`s but the second seemed to overwrite the first; in the following code `filter_thing` wasn't called for `action1`:

```
before_action :filter_thing, except: [:action3, :action4]
before_action :filter_thing, only: [:action2], unless: :should_not_filter?
```

I thought that maybe I could use a conditional `skip_before_action`:

```
skip_before_action :filter_thing, only: :action2, if: :should_not_filter?
```

but it seems to ignore the `if:` argument.

Is there a way to conditionally apply a filter to only some actions?

Answer (score 4):

This is the workaround I came up with:

```
before_action :filter_thing,
              except[:action3, :action4],
              unless: -> { params[:action] == "action2" && should_not_filter? }
```

I'm still not wholly satisfied because the above is convoluted and tough to read.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but you could try this.
Have not tested btw:

```
before_action :filter_thing, except: %i[action3 action4], unless: :filter_not

private

def filter_not
  action_name && should_not_filter?
end
```

[action_name](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Base.html#method-i-action_name)

From the api guide:

> Returns the name of the action this controller is processing.